# How to get numbers from a text file using python

Tags: python, file, python-3.x, file-io

I need to read values from a text file which the user would use to input values which would be numbers or string  .

The text file would look something like this :

```
#dimensions(a,b,t)
value of a entered 
value of b entered 
value of t entered

#Glass type(AN,HS,GT)
< type of glass entered >
```

I need to extract just the values which user enters which is values of a, b, t and the type of glass. 
 except for the type of glass everything else is an integer.

I know we use the filename.readline() for reading each line , but even if we do so, it reads as a string with the \n . Is there any way to achieve my goal?

Comment: You have to parse the string, there isn't anything magical that knows what you personally want out of it.  I suggest liberal use of find() and slices, then float() or int() as appropriate.

Comment: if you dont want the \n, use `str.strip()`. if you want to read it all as one string, use `filename.read()`

Comment: `int()` strips whtespace, so `int('   \t1   \t\r\n')` returns `1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `a` is a string, you should be able to convert it into integer or float using `int(float(a))` and `foat(a)` respectively. If you're not sure about the type of `a`, use

```
try: 
    integer = int(float(a))
except:
    <some code to handle the error>
```

Comment: Suggest you use `except ValueError:` to avoid catching unrelated exceptions.